# Intra-class correlation coefficients with R

Tags: r, correlation, intraclass-correlation

I have recorded the heart rate of a number of participants with two methods:

1. ECG
2. rPPG

I am trying to demonstrate that the rPPG is a reliable measure and I think I can use an approach similar to this paper: "*[Reliability and concurrent validity of a peripheral pulse oximeter and health–app system for the quantification of heart rate in healthy adults](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1460458214540909)*"

Here the authors have 3 measures: HR recorded  with a phone app, a pulse oximeter and with fingers on the wrist of participants. They say: "*the results of pulse measurements were compared using ICC, with a value >0.85 indicating acceptable reliability.7 Concurrent validities between the two systems (App and pulse oximeter) compared with the pulse at radial right artery were calculated using ICCs (2, 1)*

This is very similar to my situation, that is, I should be able to **use the ICC (2,1) to compare the ECG and rPPG**, right?

How do I replicate this in R?

I have 18 sbj, HR from each sbj was recorded over 2 distances (close, far) in 4 intervals for each distance (25s, 35s, 45s, 100s).

Here is my reproducible dataset

```
 `structure(list(SbjID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18), rPPGHR = c(73.568858018236, 73.9643592355794, 
75.1512629850186, 76.183665699754, 75.0124739410375, 72.9172023394378, 
73.3563679612269, 73.8272419122952, 73.6147878876805, 73.3171869846869, 
77.100032991351, 73.1826953454202, 69.6110835176462, 72.6810761695784, 
72.8450578873579, 71.2833473580327, 65.9690694756357, 66.9272604893051, 
63.7205837421735, 66.6175729836699, 68.9788357352529, 66.8315524911707, 
63.2433676232742, 66.9804285763015, 72.4798764238229, 79.157985500362, 
76.8931763704947, 74.9438837595563, 72.1125834629689, 71.6308220007823, 
75.4423236350939, 77.6675303975563, 77.6661250132802, 75.5226583917465, 
74.7665396794409, 76.5072756535853, 80.2253861713135, 82.5731801751924, 
78.1761608814803, 79.1576849721773, 69.8498507735745, 71.715936657071, 
73.1971926164406, 72.1353976384989, 71.9492767461428, 77.0148246183584, 
71.3019164418854, 72.6082043152488, 103.841078529619, 103.992373018352, 
105.861738635334, 103.77844066218, 107.871348385392, 109.959276757763, 
106.406422717789, 90.4668853432578, 94.7633251250977, 89.5566957762903, 
93.2339218762567, 89.6320096351893, 87.9426510436671, 84.3748095643791, 
86.9332235750928, 101.834265447435, 93.2906872036351, 90.1319565913137, 
91.6855118217463, 90.5973678450523, 90.8453243164162, 86.8001952639914, 
89.3792894588331, 68.4789552260627, 70.2191082843823, 62.1609748849766, 
63.4244241781614, 74.2054366675391, 68.9102293748642, 68.0675919538361, 
62.0738089162358, 84.495875769985, 79.9453378616335, 79.7258922983638, 
83.5930983307519, 87.8474262886947, 85.9995651890826, 87.0709910010164, 
83.1879723129111, 69.6141636726715, 71.843364800788, 73.5697685855847, 
69.9740287042274, 73.7688552861324, 71.2262563645388, 75.7757600101796, 
74.515137661904, 78.0893059292887, 80.6801543141242, 84.1398849614322, 
84.8213947218242, 90.7031749145672, 79.5242876032826, 85.468652239096, 
88.0363257917888, 85.2125847993314, 84.596809823031, 77.2440920086156, 
80.8430450325153, 70.2695929371369, 74.6456470490513, 76.2698430515213, 
80.7644987296781, 63.7296844775436, 60.0843666178277, 60.6059359531587, 
58.2089655213719, 57.1045288953549, 56.7642605791266, 54.5668877261591, 
58.5721150050651, 79.3993626968537, 84.6265723047072, 81.4695588971539, 
81.2112415158523, 88.9700171226849, 74.2245239678594, 71.911242841154, 
77.6529472001373, 100.793276841151, 95.2321473289922, 94.4591791403419, 
96.2575054603616, 93.416520830737, 91.9156675556897, 89.1427839508978, 
96.2931921501421, 71.6024231849469, 71.0422472379692, 68.9421479568216, 
69.443151061747, 74.1588846755054, 72.6809300698654, 68.1290827113897, 
69.4130113359389), HR_ECG = c(76.8, 75.4285714285714, 74.6666666666667, 
75.6, 76.8, 73.7142857142857, 73.3333333333333, 73.8, 74.4, 72, 
77.3333333333333, 73.8, 69.6, 73.7142857142857, 72, 72, 67.2, 
66.8571428571429, 65.3333333333333, 66.6, 67.2, 68.5714285714286, 
65.3333333333333, 67.8, 76.8, 82.2857142857143, 78.6666666666667, 
77.4, 79.2, 77.1428571428572, 77.3333333333333, 78.6, 76.8, 75.4285714285714, 
76, 77.4, 81.6, 82.2857142857143, 78.6666666666667, 79.2, 72, 
73.7142857142857, 73.3333333333333, 72, 72, 77.1428571428572, 
73.3333333333333, 73.2, 105.6, 108, 106.666666666667, 105, 110.4, 
109.333333333333, 108, 93.6, 96, 89.3333333333333, 93.6, 91.2, 
89.1428571428571, 88, 87.6, 103.2, 94.2857142857143, 90.6666666666667, 
91.8, 88.8, 92.5714285714286, 88, 89.4, 67.2, 70.2857142857143, 
62.6666666666667, 64.8, 79.2, 70.2857142857143, 66.6666666666667, 
62.4, 86.4, 78.8571428571429, 81.3333333333333, 84, 91.2, 87.4285714285714, 
86.6666666666667, 83.4, 67.2, 73.7142857142857, 74.6666666666667, 
69.6, 74.4, 73.7142857142857, 76, 75, 88.8, 84, 85.3333333333333, 
85.2, 91.2, 84, 86.6666666666667, 88.2, 86.4, 84, 77.3333333333333, 
81.6, 72, 75.4285714285714, 76, 81, 62.4, 61.7142857142857, 61.3333333333333, 
58.8, 57.6, 58.2857142857143, 56, 58.8, 81.6, 82.2857142857143, 
82.6666666666667, 85.2, 86.4, 84, 82.6666666666667, 84.6, 100.8, 
101.142857142857, 94.6666666666667, 96.6, 98.4, 99.4285714285714, 
98.6666666666667, 96.6, 72, 72, 69.3333333333333, 69.6, 74.4, 
73.7142857142857, 69.3333333333333, 69.6), Distance = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), duration = c(25, 
35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 
25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 
100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 
45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 
45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 
35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 
25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 
100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 
45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100, 25, 
35, 45, 100, 25, 35, 45, 100)), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 67L, 69L, 70L, 72L, 
73L, 74L, 75L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 87L, 88L, 
89L, 90L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 102L, 103L, 
104L, 105L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 117L, 
118L, 119L, 120L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 
132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 
145L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 157L, 158L, 
159L, 160L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 172L, 
173L, 174L, 175L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L), class = "data.frame")`
```

This is what I tried:

```
iccData = subVars %>%
  select(rPPGHR, HR_ECG)

library("irr")
icc(iccData, model = "twoway",
    type = "agreement", unit = "single")
```

Is this the same model that was used in the paper, that is, ICC(2,1)?
If so, the output says:

```
    Single Score Intraclass Correlation

   Model: twoway 
   Type : agreement 

   Subjects = 143 
     Raters = 2 
   ICC(A,1) = 0.975

 F-Test, H0: r0 = 0 ; H1: r0 > 0 
F(142,15.2) = 103 , p = 2.11e-13 

 95%-Confidence Interval for ICC Population Values:
  0.939 < ICC < 0.987
```

It says "**Subjects = 143**" it matter that some of the scores are actually from the same participants (19 sbj and not 143)?

Comment: Thank you Allan